# Android Manifest Validate errors with uses-permissions

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

So, I am trying to use the built in contact picker in my android application, but I got the following error for this line:

```
  cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ id,null, null);
```

The error:

```
Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 uri content://com.android.contacts/data/phones from pid=11135, uid=10057 requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS, or grantUriPermission()
```

So, I figured I have to add the uses-permission in my AndroidManifest.xml like so (this is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="balevski.meetme" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

So, I rebuilt my project after adding the READ_CONTACTS permission, and I still get the same issue.

Next, I validated my AndroidManifest.xml file, and the following errors are shown:

```
C:\Users\dbale\AndroidStudioProjects\MeetMe\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
Error:(2, 97) cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'manifest'.
Error:(1, 56) s4s-elt-schema-ns: The namespace of element 'x' must be from the schema namespace, 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.
Error:(1, 56) s4s-elt-invalid: Element 'x' is not a valid element in a schema document.
Error:(1, 56) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'null', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

Here is my Gradle app file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "balevski.meetme"
    minSdkVersion 7
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
}
```

I am new the android studio and if someone can help me figure out this issue!

Much appreciated.

Comment: clean your project and rebuilt it

Comment: I have tried cleaning and rebuilding. Still not working.

Comment: `I validated my AndroidManifest.xml file` with the w3schools xml validator? Yeah there is no need to do this and I'm not surprised it failed, don't worry about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On marshmallow (Android 6.0 / api 23) devices you now need to request the permission at runtime, it is not good enough to just put it in the manifest any more.

http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

From the docs:

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

        // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but, could you provide a little more explanation for me please? What is the variable "MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS" ? What do I set that as. - Also, can I not just ask for a one time requestPermission so that they dont have to be asked every time they want to get contact info?

Comment: read the URL I linked you. Yes you can ask for permission once and they can say to remember this choice

Answer (score 0):

Clear `.idea` file in project folder and try to rebuild the project.